# Replace map with new map (and new options) - Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a website that creates a map with several markers.

Long story short, I now want a function, that when called, creates a new map to replace the old with with several new options without reloading the page.

I have tried several things to no avail. My most recent attempt was to clear the div containing the map and create one anew as before.

i.e.

```
    function replaceMap() {

        $('#map-canvas').empty();

        var map2;
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
            };
            map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    }
```

This successfully removed the old map, but nothing more.

Am I on the right track?

I'm happy using jQuery but have very little experience so I'd need some help.

Answer (score 0):

If you try with one iframe and set the new src in iframe, i havea site with this mode and working fine.

You can see how to work in my site. 
http://www.skinnygirldaily.com/s.nl/sc.23/.f

Comment: In the grand scheme of things, the new map will have options which will rely on user input so it has to be more dynamic that just an iframe

Comment: You can set the new map with parameters from url, i think.
Try with a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
      //this recived the parameters to set google maps     

     function myGetUrlVars() {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var url = window.location.href.replace(/&amp;/gi, '&');
    var hashes = url.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split(
            '&_');
    for ( var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}


//*******************************start google api ****************//

params = myGetUrlVars();
var option = params['option'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `initialize` currently  will only be called only 1 time(when the `onload` of the `window` fires).

However, it's not a good idea to use `$.empty()` , it will probably introduce memory-leaks.

Use the existing map, remove the markers and use `setOptions()` to apply the new options

Comment: Thanks. I tried this before and ran into a lot of trouble but if that's the best way. I'll have another go